# Wordpress and SSL

Tags: ssl

I've made some changes so the blog will work using SSL (`https://`) but now I cannot access my blog anymore - every time I try to access it I'm redirected to `https://example.com`, eventhough I try to acess to `http://example.com`.

I can fix it if by adding this two lines to the `wp-config.php` file:

```
define( 'WP_HOME',    'http://example.com' );
define( 'WP_SITEURL', 'http://example.com' );
```

But I can't use SSL using this fix. Why am I redirected automatically to the `https://` when I want to access the blog through `http://`? How can i change it back?

Answer (score 0):

I believe generally, a website is either secure (SSL), or it's not. If you needed to activate SSL for a portion of your website, you should keep it all as `https://`. There is no drawback to doing so. If anything, it will give people more confidence in your website.

Those 2 links you have mentioned override database defaults. There are 2 ways to set them:

**With Database/phpMyAdmin access**
 - go into the `wp_options` tables, and change the `site_url` (entry 1) and `home` (entry 36) values, just remove the `s`.

**Without Database Access**
 - put the following line into your `wp-config.php` file, access `http://domain.com/wp-login.php` directly, not using `/wp-admin`. Log into the site, then remove this line.

```
define( 'WP_REDIRECT', true );
```

You could also just leave those 2 lines in the config file. They won't hurt anything except for when you try pulling the site to another domain/staging server.

Comment: See updated answer for 2 ways to change the protocol in your site.

Comment: I don't have DB access. I tried putting define( 'WP_REDIRECT', true ); directly in the wp-config.php, instead of the 2 lines and it didn't work. I'm Still redirected automatically to the https:// address so i can't access the http://. I would have kept the 2 lines but i want to work with SSL in the future.

Comment: If you want to work with SSL in the future, just take them out when you are ready. You're pretty limited without DB access at this point.